# Patch Hole In HardiPlank Fiber Cement Siding

Tags: siding, hole, patch, cement-board, putty

I have a hole in the siding of my home. The siding is HardiPlank fiber cement. The hole size (diameter) is that of a cable line. A cable line was run through the siding when the previous home owners lived there but the cable line is no longer there. I want to patch the hole if possible. I really do not want to replace the board. However, I have not found a product specifically made for patching fiber cement siding. I did come across an all-purpose putty [Bondo](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-Bondo-Home-Solutions-1-gal-All-Purpose-Putty-Case-of-2-20054/202202185?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD24%7CMulti%7CNA%7CPLA%7CAll_RLSA_Paint%7C71700000032326069%7C58700003839194770%7C92700030688282692&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItZKb57uS2gIVEh2BCh0hRwBqEAQYASABEgLrzPD_BwE&dclid=CKK73ui7ktoCFdRlwQod18UNfw) but I am not sure if this will do the trick or not.

Any suggestions on what material to use would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hole relatively small i would use [Quad window and door sealant](http://www.ositough.com/en/products/view-all-products/weather-resistant-sealant-quad.html). Not affiliated but i use it. It will stay flexible,  cement siding can expand and contract with high and low temps. It comes in many colors.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This seems to be what I needed. Thank you!